# Alter table command is not working in mysql after I insert a few rows

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

```
mysql> select * from ATRs;
+-----+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
| Id  | Name_       | Team          | Goals | Trophies |
+-----+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
| 110 | Messi       | Barcelona     |   699 |        0 |
| 107 | Ronaldo     | Juventus      |    60 |        0 |
| 107 | Ronaldo     | Real Madrid   |    60 |        0 |
| 109 | Lewandowski | Bayern Munich |   400 |       10 |
| 109 | Lewansowski | Dortmund      |    88 |        4 |
| 210 | Neymar      | Barcelona     |   121 |        9 |
| 210 | Neymar      | Paris         |    48 |        1 |
+-----+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is my table right now

```
alter table ATRs change Name_ Name varchar(22);
```

After this command the server doesn't respond at all and whatever i write after that is just treated as a plain text.

Comment: Show us a `SHOW CREATE TABLE ATRs;` and copy/paste the output to your question please

Comment: How are you submitting the alter statement - via command line , some ide?

Answer (score 0):

Please rename column rather than changing

```
ALTER TABLE ATRs RENAME COLUMN Name_ TO Name;
```

Comment: Change is valid why would rename be better?

Comment: It they don't require to change the datatype/length, Rename can be used. According to the question seems to be wanted to rename from Name_ TO Name. In this case change of datatype/ length is not required

Answer (score 0):

[NAME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N) is a keyword. Try using backticks.

`` alter table ATRs change `Name_` `Name` varchar(22); ``

Comment: Actually only the word with a `(R)` are the reserved words, so name is a keyword

Comment: Edited my answer. Thanks.